# Get substring location within a given string

Tags: r, string

Consider the string:

```
a <- "this is a string"
```

Now, `grep` can be used to confirm the presence of substrings:

```
grep("t",a)
grep("this",a)
```

But doesn't seem to give the location.

Is there a function that will give me the location of any substring?

```
getLoction(a, "t")
## 1 12

getLoction(a, "this")
## 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, I'm partial to the stringr package:

```
library(stringr)
a <- "this is a string"
str_locate(a,"t")
str_locate(a,"this")
str_locate_all(a,"t")
```

and the output:

```
> str_locate(a,"t")
     start end
[1,]     1   1
> str_locate(a,"this")
     start end
[1,]     1   4
> str_locate_all(a,"t")
[[1]]
     start end
[1,]     1   1
[2,]    12  12
```